# How to optimise Haskell code to pass HackerRanks timed out test cases (Not for any ongoing competition, just me practicing)

Tags: algorithm, haskell, haskell-platform

I been learning Haskell for around 4 months now and I have to say, the learning curve is definitely hard(scary also :p).

After solving about 15 easy questions, today I moved to my first medium difficulty problem on HackerRank https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem.

It was 10 test cases and I am able to pass 6 of them, but the rest fail with timeout, now the interesting part is, I can already see a few parts that have potential for performance increase, for example, I am using `nub` to remove duplicated from a `[Int]`, but still I am not able to build a mental model for algorithmic performance, the main cause of that being unsure about Haskell compiler will change my code and how laziness plays a role here.

```
import Data.List (nub)

getInputs :: [String] -> [String]
getInputs (_:r:_:p:[]) = [r, p]

findRating :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Int
findRating step _ [] = step
findRating step point (x:xs) = if point >= x then step else findRating (step + 1) point xs

solution :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
solution [rankings, points] = map (\p -> findRating 1 p duplicateRemovedRatings) points
                            where duplicateRemovedRatings = nub rankings


main :: IO ()
main = interact (unlines . map show . solution . map (map read . words) . getInputs . lines)
```

Test Case in GHCI

```sh
:l "solution"
let i = "7\n100 100 50 40 40 20 10\n4\n5 25 50 120"
solution i // "6\n4\n2\n1\n"
```

Specific questions I have:

- Will the `duplicateRemovedRankings` variable be calculated once, or on each iteration of the map function call.
- Like in imperative programming languages, I can verify the above question using some sort of printing mechanism, is there some equivalent way of doing the same with Haskell.
- According to my current understanding, the complexity of this algorithm would be, I know `nub` is `O(n^2)`

  - `findRating` is `O(n)`
  - `getInputs` is `O(1)`
  - `solution` is `O(n^2)`

How can I reason about this and build a mental model for performance.

If this violates community guidelines, please comment and I will delete this. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: To answer the easy questions: once, and `Debug.Trace.trace`.

Comment: `nub` is horrible, only use it on lists that you know in advance are very small.

Comment: Use `Data.IntSet` and `Data.Map.Strict` from the `containers` package (included with ghc), and your time complexity goes down to `min(n * log n, m)` where `n` is `ranked` length and `m` is `player` length.

Comment: @user1984 did you mean min(n * log n, m * log n)? we get O(n+m) with lists which is probably better. I describe it in a comment [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69465400/how-to-optimise-haskell-code-to-pass-hackerranks-timed-out-test-cases-not-for-a/69466538#comment122783579_69466538). (unless I'm missing something)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First**, to answer your questions:

1. Yes, `duplicateRemovedRankings` is computed only once. No repeated computation.
2. To debug-trace, you can use [`trace`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.12/base-4.14.3.0/Debug-Trace.html#v:trace) and its friends (see the docs for examples and explanation). Yes, it can be used even in pure, non-IO code. But obviously, don't use it for "normal" output.
3. Yes, your understanding of complexity is correct.

---

**Now**, how to pass HackerRank's tricky tests.

First, yes, you're right that `nub` is O(N^2). However, in this particular case you don't have to settle for that. You can use the fact that the rankings come pre-sorted to get a linear version of `nub`. All you have to do is skip elements while they're equal to the next one:

```
betterNub (x:y:rest) 
  | x == y = betterNub (y:rest)
  | otherwise = x : betterNub (y:rest)
betterNub xs = xs
```

This gives you O(N) for `betterNub` itself, but it's still not good enough for HackerRank, because the overall solution is still O(N*M) - for each game you are iterating over all rankings. No bueno.

But here you can get another improvement by observing that the rankings are *sorted*, and searching in a sorted list doesn't have to be linear. You can use a binary search instead!

To do this, you'll have to get yourself constant-time indexing, which can be achieved by using [`Array`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.12/array-0.5.4.0/Data-Array.html#t:Array) instead of list.

Here's my implementation (please don't judge harshly; I realize I probably got edge cases overengineered, but hey, it works!):

```
import Data.Array (listArray, bounds, (!))

findIndex arr p
  | arr!end' > p = end' + 1
  | otherwise = go start' end'
  where
    (start', end') = bounds arr

    go start end =
      let mid = (start + end) `div` 2
          midValue = arr ! mid
      in
        if midValue == p then mid
        else if mid == start then (if midValue < p then start else end)
        else if midValue < p then go start mid
        else go mid end

solution :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
solution [rankings, points] = map (\p -> findIndex duplicateRemovedRatings p + 1) points
                            where duplicateRemovedRatings = toArr $ betterNub rankings

toArr l = listArray (0, (length l - 1)) l
```

With this, you get O(log N) for the search itself, making the overall solution O(M * log N). And this seems to be good enough for HackerRank.

(note that I'm adding 1 to the result of `findIndex` - this is because the exercise requires 1-based index)

Comment: why all this? the description states "The player's scores, `player`, are in ***ascending*** order." (emphasis mine). we just need to wind _forth_ over the leaderboard rankings list `ranked` getting it reversed, while also converting it to RLE format, until we get to the first play's score; then as we play more we wind it _back_ by popping head elements off while possibly updating the current head entry. `reverse&rle` is O(n) and so is `toArray`. the popping has O(m+n) total cost. am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, I totally missed the fact that the players are also sorted. Oh well... Still, even O(M * log N) passes all the tests 

Comment: `betterNub = map head . group`

Comment: Yeah, but I wanted to show the idea and how it would work.

Answer (score 3):

I believe Fyodor's answer is excellent for your first two and a half questions. For the final half, "How can I build a mental model for performance?", I can say that SPJ is an absolute master of writing highly technical papers in a way accessible to the smart but ignorant reader. The implementation book [Implementing lazy functional languages on stock hardware](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.53.3729&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is excellent and can serve as the basis of a mental execution model. There is also Okasaki's thesis, [Purely functional data structures](https://search.proquest.com/openview/107673a005c7a62188947e6379f0ea08/1.pdf?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=18750&diss=y&casa_token=2cLKcIzBr-0AAAAA:SwLY26PhB30rYWymhZ5tdC4MCcDUcCheHMlc9NGQrVXI0OZGqB2kuGdoBHkvp8EFtEd9iLnd30Q), which discusses a complementary and significantly higher-level approach to doing asymptotic complexity analyses. (Actually, I read his book, which apparently includes some extra content, so bear that in mind when deciding for yourself about this recommendation.)

Please don't be daunted by their length. I personally found they were actually actively fun to read; and the topic they cover is a big one, not compressible to a short/quick answer.

Comment: upvote just for calling my answer excellent. I am super vain :-)